# Надо-значит-надо

Tags: пунктуация

Сказал надо значит надо!

Уважаемые знатоки русского языка, подскажите, как правильно оформить это устоявшееся выражение? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Обычно обсуждается вариант "Надо - значит, надо".

Это БСП, поэтому ставится тире, а в форме СПП это выглядит следующим образом: "Раз (если) надо,  значит, надо".

РАЗ...ЗНАЧИТ - двойной союз, при этом вторая часть сближается с вводным словом, поэтому ставится запятая. (Это последняя установка, не так давно запятая после "значит" не ставилась).

2) "Сказал "надо" - значит, надо". Это также БСП, в первой части упрощенное оформление прямой речи (в роли дополнения, нет двоеточия, строчная буква).

Comment: Грамота.ру предлагает еще вариант "Надо значит надо" (значит - сказуемое): http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search_answer/?s=%ED%E0%E4%EE+%E7%ED%E0%F7%E8%F2+.

Comment: Мне кажется. смысл выражения заключается в оттенках значения для слова "надо": если надо (=необходимо), значит, надо (=следует). Этот смысл, а также паузу в речи, лучше всего передает вариант "Надо - значит, надо". Запись "Надо значит надо" лаконична, но она имеет смысл "Надо означает надо", который не слишком ясен, да и пауза не обозначена.